# How to use % inside \write18 command?

Tags: shell-escape, write

I'm doing this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\write18{echo '100%' > hash.tex}
\input{hash.tex}
\end{document}
```

However, this doesn't work (doesn't compile). What is the workaround?

Comment: `\@percentchar` (you need `\makeatletter` first if not in package code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `%` is the comment character, you cannot use it that way. There are various solutions available.

The simplest one is to use `\@percentchar`, but this requires `\makeatletter`. Simpler is to define an alias in the preamble and use it inside `\write`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter\let\percentchar\@percentchar\makeatother

\begin{document}

\immediate\write18{echo '100\percentchar' > hash.tex}
\input{hash.tex}

\end{document}
```

Less obtrusive might be

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{shellesc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\exec}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\%\@percentchar
  \ShellEscape{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\exec{echo '100\%' > hash.tex}
\input{hash.tex}

\end{document}
```

Why `shellesc`? Because `\ShellEscape` works with all engines, so you don't need to change code with LuaLaTeX, for instance. It does `\immediate\write18` (or the equivalent), which is what you need: without `\immediate`, the execution would be deferred to the next page shipout and the subsequent `\input` would fail.

Answer (score 1):

You can define `\sstring` macro which behaves like `\string` but the backslash is not printed. (Note, that LuaTeX has special primitive `\cssting` for such task.

```
\def\sstring#1{\expandafter\sstringA\string#1\relax}
\def\sstringA#1#2\relax{#2}

\write18{echo '100\sstring\%' > hash.tex}
```

This is universal solution for all TeX-sensitive characters, for example `\sstring\{`, `\sstring\#` etc.

Comment: By the way this macro is \cs_to_str:N in expl3. Also you have a typo in "csstring"